# Display a key value where a key is always changing

Tags: php, json

I have a php class that grabs data from a json api call. I want to grab a specific value from a specific key, however the key is based on date and time, so it is always changing. I thought about creating a variable that uses Date() and matches their format, but I am hoping there is an easier way.

Here is the json

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "UGA",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-06-20 11:47:00",
        "4. Interval": "1min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (1min)": {
        "2017-06-20 11:47:00": {
            "1. open": "22.7500",
            "2. high": "22.7500",
            "3. low": "22.7500",
            "4. close": "22.7500",
            "5. volume": "200"
        },
        "2017-06-20 10:38:00": {
            "1. open": "22.6000",
            "2. high": "22.6000",
            "3. low": "22.6000",
            "4. close": "22.6000",
            "5. volume": "300"
        }
}
```

This is what my php looks like

```
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $json = json_decode($result, true);

            echo $json["Time Series (1min)"]["2017-06-20 11:47:00"]["1. open"];
```

Comment: if the array is being used just once you could do this: `$el = array_shift($json["Time Series (1min)"]);` then  `echo ["1. open"];` from that.

Comment: You should never use a value that can change as a key, for reasons that should now be obvious to you from running into this problem

Comment: If there's more than one, how do you know which one you want?

Comment: I don't have control over how the json is being displayed. The API i am pulling from, you set your options in a url, and it spits on the data in this format. But i only want the "1. open" value for the two most current dates.

Comment: In that case, as @Landen posted -- you can use `array_shift()` to pull the first item off the front of an array. If you want the first two items, just do it twice.